# How to define keywords in robot fw using Dynamic library APIs

Tags: robotframework

Everywhere we find only option to create keyword(call keywords) under a test, using below procedure.

```
from robot.api import SuiteVisitor

class MyVisitor(SuiteVisitor):

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def start_suite(self, suite):
        for i in range(3):
            tc = suite.tests.create(name='Dynamic Test #%s' % i)
            tc.keywords.create(name='Log', args=['Hello from test case #%s' % i])
```

**But how do we define keywords under a suite, using APIs?**
like suite.keywords.create and add multiple keywords call to it?